# Testing a code in Python Try/Except Block

Tags: python, unit-testing, try-except

```
try:
    context.do_something()
except ValueError:
   return False
```

I do i test this particular code. When i use side effort e.g.

```
context = mock.MagicMoc()
context.do_something.side_effect = ValueError
```

When i use pytest.raises, the test passes but the code is not tested.
I have tried using assert but it fails

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're wrapping the try/except code in a function that you want to test. Here are two options to test this.

1) Use a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/context-managers.html) to check that an exception is raised, after changing your function to re-raise the ValueError (though if you're not going to do anything with it, you might as well just not catch it in the first place):

```py
from unittest import TestCase, mock

def do_something(c):
    try:
        c.do_something()
    except ValueError as e:
        raise e

class TestSomething(TestCase):
    def test_do_something(self):
        context = mock.MagicMock()

        context.do_something.side_effect = ValueError

        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            do_something(context)
```

2) Return True in the successful control path of your function, then just check this condition in your test:

```py
from unittest import TestCase, mock

def do_something(c):
    try:
        c.do_something()
        return True
    except ValueError as e:
        return False

class TestSomething(TestCase):
    def test_do_something(self):
        context = mock.MagicMock()

        context.do_something.side_effect = ValueError

        self.assertTrue(do_something(context))
```